# How can I run requests or something similar in multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-requests, multiprocessing

I wrote a crawler with requests (I use session, get and post), but it slowly.. so I want run this program in mutliprocessing(e.g. 12 processes). But when I use it, its not working, everything looks fine, but something it's wrong because it makes gets and posts, but they wrong. I don't know, it is a cookies or something else...

I tried copy directory to another and run two programs in two consoles but it's no working.

Maybe can I do get and post with another library? Its just simple get and post data.

Thanks for help

Comment: Try scrapy, it is a framework which allows multiple requests. https://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Python version, you could use asynchronous tasks, and await the response, while starting other asynchronous requests in the background.

But I also made once a solution with multiprocessing, that sent multiple requests to a flight search website for multiple dates and multiple destinations. Here is some code excerpt:

```py
from billiard.pool import Pool
import requests

def perform_request(i):
    destination, date = i
    url = 'https://api.skypicker.com/flights/'
    r = requests.get(url, params={"from": "MUC", "to": destination, "date": date})


def f(destinations, dates):
    for destination in destinations:
        for date in dates:
            yield (destination, date)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    destinations = [...]
    dates = [...]
    n_threads = 5

    pool = Pool(n_threads)
    iterable = f(destinations, dates)
    pool.map(perform_request, iterable)
```

Comment: I tried something similiar, but I use session and this not working with multiprocessing (its working, but not correctly).